# How to add dynamic link to a google form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-forms

I have a system that saves customer data.
I need to send the customers 2-3 times a year a google document - a very long, tedious and annoying to fill - which they sometimes reluctant to fill.

so we want to change the document to be a google form where every question has a pre-defined answer options, which make it more user friendly and fast.

Yet, there is a small part that needs to be filled in a google document (with tables, not possible to do in google form)
each customer has its own google doc (created in advance), and I have a link for each customer's google doc.
can i create a form that will have 20 constant questions, and the 21st question will have a link, unique per customer?

is there a way to do something similar?

Comment: You can't do it, what you can do is when user fills the 20 question and submit the form, you can send this document on their email automatically and ask them to submit it through another form.

Comment: Alternatively you can create a script to create a form per user and save the responses to the same spreadsheet for collation

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you can create a script that creates a Google Form for each of your users.

Here is an example of how this can be accomplished:

```js
const USER_DATA = [
  {
    name: "USER1",
    email: "USER1@gmail.com",
    doc_url: "https://docs.google.com/document/d/USER_1_ID/edit"
  },
  /* ETC */
]

const createSingleForm = ({ name, email, doc_url }, ss_id) => {
  const form = FormApp.create(`Form for ${name}`)
  /* COMMON PART */
  const q1 = form.addCheckboxItem();
  q1.setTitle('Are you happy?')
    .setChoices([
      q1.createChoice('Yes'),
      q1.createChoice('Only on friday'),
    ])
    .showOtherOption(true);
  /* CUSTOM PART */
  const qCustomForUser = form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
  qCustomForUser
    .setTitle(`Please fill this Google Doc ${doc_url}`)
    .setChoices([
      qCustomForUser.createChoice('Done it!'),
    ])
  /* This will associate with a created Spreadsheet to keep track of the answers */
  form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss_id)
  return form.getPublishedUrl()
}

const createAllForms = () => {
  const destinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('Results of Forms').getId()
  USER_DATA.forEach((user) => {
    const formURL = createSingleForm(user, destinationSheet)
    GmailApp.sendEmail(user.email, 'Fill this form', `Please ${user.name}, fill this form ${formURL}`)
  })
}
```

A description of what the script does:

1. Create an array of objects that includes the relevant data, in my example: name, email and Google Docs URL.
2. Create a function that creates a Form for each user, this will have two parts:

   - The common part for all users, in my example `q1`. This will repeat to `q20` as you explain.
   - The custom part for each user, in my example `qCustomForUser`. In this part you can reference the Google DOC defined in your user object.
3. **OPTIONAL** Associate the Form with a Sheet to keep track of the responses. You can also handle it by [`onFormSubmit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onformsubmit)
4. Create a function that loops `USER_DATA`, creates a Google Form for each user and sends them an email.

This is an example script and you have to customize it to suit your needs.

##### Documentation

- [FormApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app)
- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app)
- [DestinationType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/destination-type)

Comment: Hello! What if i can only have one Form, that asks "Yes/No"? I tried your code and it did'nt work...

Comment: `This is an example script and you have to customize it to suit your needs.`

Comment: Is it possible to create a single forms link but using datas in a google sheet ? Ex: FormID = Select ID from Spread Sheet column B ... Then, create Google Form link by using formLink = "Google Form Link" + FormID